# Asked to approve own close votes

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

If I vote to close a question, then review close votes, I sometimes see that same question again. So it seems I get to approve my own close votes. I find it hard to believe that is by design. Is it a bug?

Comment: When you say you "mark a question for closure", do you mean you vote to close it? And when you write "review close votes" you're talking about /review/close? Because then, yes - that's a bug. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: I refrained from using my double strength close votes. Do I get a biscuit?

Comment: Does clicking the close button actually do anything?

Comment: What if you click "Leave Open"? Does it undo your close vote?

Comment: I've not tried voting to leave open.